# Staying longer as a postdoc vs doing another postdoc elsewhere

Tags: postdocs, career-path, early-career

I am currently on the third year of a postdoctoral fellowship that is due to finish in ~10 months. I'm looking into faculty positions, but I take into account that I might not succeed in getting one immediately. This is my first postdoc and if I want to continue in academia, I see two possible strategies for the short term.

One is to stay longer in the group I'm working with - my advisor has funding to extend my contract by at least a year or maybe even longer. The other is to do a second postdoc elsewhere.

The first option sounds attractive because it would not require applying to postdoc jobs at the same time as faculty jobs. In addition, I could continue working with my current advisor and take more projects from him. He knows what I am capable of and it could be a productive time in terms of research output.

The second option also has its advantages, as I would be able to branch out to a different research direction as well as acquire a larger network of people. Just like people in industry do job-hopping, this sounds like a way of increasing and diversifying my work experience.

Apart from personal preferences, what would be a better strategy, (a) assuming I want to eventually move into faculty-level positions, (b) in all other cases where I don't succeed or decide not to advance to becoming a PI.

For reference, I'm based in Europe (currently Germany) and plan to stay here.

Comment: In the US there is a pretty common rhythm to faculty hiring, with postings in the fall, interviews in the spring, and appointments starting the next August/September. Is that the case in Europe as well? The timing of these cycles vs the post-doc duration has impacts as one can imagine.

Comment: Where do you think you could do better work, and what is your time frame?  For just an extra year, moving might not be worth it, but moving to a place that could significantly enhance your research for a few years could be.

Comment: @JonCuster It depends on the country, but generally there is not a fixed schedule for faculty openings. Some specific funding schemes for junior PI positions do have fixed deadlines (e.g. in the UK), but in most other cases positions are posted as they come up.

Comment: @Kimball Thanks! I'm satisfied with my current workplace, but my research direction is veering off into an area that somewhat diverges with what the rest of the department. Therefore it might make sense to seek a new place in terms of research interests. However, in many other aspects (research infrastructure, location, pay, etc.) there are only few places in Europe that offer similarly high standards, so changing place might require compromising on a few of these aspects unfortunately.

Comment: Can you clarify b)?  Does it mean leaving academia?

Comment: Yes, either leaving academia or taking a non-PI position in academia (e.g. in administration). Not sure if it makes any difference.

Comment: @PianoEntropy I can speak towards Europe, but this may be quite discipline-specific. Can you specify your discipline?

Comment: @GrotesqueSI My discipline is theoretical biophysics & computational biology, somewhere on the border between the two fields (physics & biology).